# Export boundaries as gpx file from Open Street Map?

Tags: openstreetmap, export, gpx, boundaries

How can I export the boundaries of this area as GPX? Is there any way?

https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/1595533#map=14/50.8945/14.3287

Background: I'm planing a hiking tour through the national part but you're not allowed to camp in the inner zone of the park. Sadly I couldn't find any official gpx data download.

Comment: Note that boundaries in OSM (or any other map service) can deviate from the official boundaries. Always look for local signs. The Kernzone of the Nationalpark Sächsische Schweiz is marked by signs. Look out for them, usually they are easy to spot.

Comment: Thank you, yes, I'm aware of that. I just needed something to know roughly where I'm allowed to camp for planing purposes. Just in case I have to sleep outside. I want to try to get the whole trail in 5 days done. :) So I want to make sure that one of my stages doesn't end in the middle of the core zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query and export data from Openstreetmap via [overpass turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/).

It's Wizard is quite easy to handle. Just search for the tags provided in your link like this:

[image]

Which produces the following query you can execute:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “boundary=national_park and name="Nationalpark Sächsische Schweiz (Kernzone)"”
  node["boundary"="national_park"]["name"="Nationalpark Sächsische Schweiz (Kernzone)"]({{bbox}});
  way["boundary"="national_park"]["name"="Nationalpark Sächsische Schweiz (Kernzone)"]({{bbox}});
  relation["boundary"="national_park"]["name"="Nationalpark Sächsische Schweiz (Kernzone)"]({{bbox}});
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Here is a working link: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/JQc

You can export the data as GeoJSON, GPX or KML.

Comment: Thank you! :) Works perfect!